# msys2 won't recognize driver folder as valid

Tags: python, pyodbc, msys2

I have a python program that uses an ODBC connection, so needs to locate the database drivers.  Since I couldn't get pyodbc to install on my mingw64 version of python (I'm told pyodbc has hardcoded MSVC flags making it very difficult to do), I instead am using a regular windows python install that I'm running from within msys2 by just altering my path to point to that python install (maybe there is more that I should be doing to target a different python install?)

Now the problem I'm running into is that while the program runs fine in powershell using that version of python, when I try running it within msys2 I get the following error:

> conn = pyodbc.connect(link)

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be
loaded due to system error  126: The specified module could not be found.
(Teradata, C:\\Program Files\\Teradata\\Client\\14.10\\ODBC Driver for
Teradata nt-x8664\\Lib\\tdata32.dll). (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The thing is that directory is correct and I can even run

```
cd "C:\\Program Files\\Teradata\\Client\\14.10\\ODBC Driver for Teradata nt-x8664\\Lib\\"
```

from within msys2 and it works just fine and recognizes that directory as valid and it contains a file named tdata32.dll.  Using `winpty python myprogram.py` didn't resolve this either.

So why can't my system find this driver directory but only when I'm running the python program from msys2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that tdata32.dll depends on other DLLs, and one of them is not being found because it is not on the PATH when you run Python from MSYS2.

Try adding a line of Python code to print the contents of your PATH environment variable in both environments to examine the issue.

You can also use [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what DLLs tdata32.dll depends on.